problem with playing m3u8 file with low latency
I tried to use ffmpeg to convert the incoming rtmps stream and write into m3u8 file and ts files. The problem arises when I set hls_flags split_by_time and the hls player refuse to play even when all files are fetched successfully, occasionally when I refresh the HLS player or play with VLC, it play smoothly without troubles. I've read that because 2 seconds were too short for ffmpeg to generate a keyframe for ts file so first few ts files all have close to 0 second (0.33, 0.64, ...), I open some ts files in folder and some have 0 sec and doesn't have any image. However when I set -g, -keyint_min, -force_key_frames to resolve the problem as the code below, it still persists.
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-fflags', 'nobuffer',
        '-i', streamUrl,
        '-c:v', 'copy',
        '-c:a', 'copy',
        '-g', '30',                       
        '-keyint_min', '30',             
        '-sc_threshold', '0',             
        '-force_key_frames', 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)', 
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',        
        '-f', 'hls',
        '-hls_time', '2',                
        '-hls_list_size', '3', 
        '-hls_flags', 'split_by_time', 
        '-hls_allow_cache', '0',
        '-strftime', '1',
        '-hls_segment_type', 'mpegts',
        '-hls_segment_filename', segmentPath,
        '-tune', 'zerolatency',           
        '-max_interleave_delta', '0',     
        outputPath
    ], { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore' });

I tried to set hls_flags to independent_segments, it ran smoothly but now every m3u8 file it generated all have target duration of 8.33 seconds, which is not what I want since I want the latency to be around 3-5 seconds. -hls_flags delete_segments is a no go since I need the ts files for other purpose.
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:8.334000,
segment-20241030-193759.ts
#EXTINF:8.333000,
segment-20241030-193811.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

Can somebody help me how to achieve 2 seconds target duration while every ts file at least have a keyframe so the HLS Player can play, or anything at all since I'm not sure that I grasp the problem correctly.
